# Bootstrap navigation bar has no style

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

So I've been coding a bootstrap navigation bar on my WordPress theme and it has no style at all. Screenshot below.

[image]

This is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-digital fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'primary',
            'container' => false,
            'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-left'
        ));
    ?>
</nav>
```

My `bootstrap.min.css` is above my website css in the head section so let me get that out of the way. The source code:

```
<div class="nav-container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-digital fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-6"><a href="http://localhost/punky/">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7"><a href="http://localhost/punky/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
        </ul>                       
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure that bootstrap is including or available on the right path?

Comment: Check by inspecting element are styles with that classes loaded on the page.

Comment: In your tags for the question you state bootstrap 4 but the markup that you are showing is for bootstrap 3.

Comment: @sunilkumar yes, i'm sure.

Comment: @StupidKid i've included the source code, check

Comment: @SteveK So what would be the right 4.0 markup?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Ohhhhhhh........................... I said check is it loaded not did you include it or not sometimes when I add new css it won't load until I clean cache etc..

Comment: @SteveK now the navbar completely disappeared lol. could it be because of the missing `nav-item` in `li`? But how would you add that in wordpress?

Comment: @SteveK I've fixed that with a walker class but still nothing. I'm confused.

Comment: If you are using the fixed-top class it may be a z-index issue and it is just hiding behind something on your page.  It is hard to tell for me not really being able to see your code or inspect things.  Is it showing up in your page source in your dev console?

Comment: Also I see that your nav is wrapped in a container if you are using the fixed class you would probably want the parent to your nav to be the body if you are using the fixed-top class try removing it and see if your nav shows up if it does then you know thats your problem.

Comment: @SteveK Yeah I noticed that, I removed the class, didn't fix the problem. I'm going to use an older version of bootstrap, i can't be bothered, it's wasting so much of my time. Appreciate the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `'theme_location'` as `primary`. Did you check if your Menu location is same:

[image: Menu Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if in the source in development tools is loading the bootstrap file? Check if you select the location of the menu too.